# Get the count based on column in the table in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, unpivot

Need to get the `ColumnName2` values when the right columns having > 1 'Y' value from the below sample table.

```
ColumnName1 ColumnName2     ColumnName3 ColumnName4 ColumnName5 ColumnName6
----------- --------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           ROWNUMBER1      Y           NULL        NULL        NULL
2           ROWNUMBER2      NULL        Y           NULL        NULL
3           ROWNUMBER3      NULL        NULL        Y           NULL
4           ROWNUMBER4      NULL        NULL        NULL        Y
5           ROWNUMBER5      Y           Y           NULL        NULL
6           ROWNUMBER6      NULL        Y           Y           NULL
7           ROWNUMBER7      NULL        NULL        Y           Y
8           ROWNUMBER8      Y           NULL        NULL        Y
9           ROWNUMBER9      Y           Y           Y           NULL
10          ROWNUMBER10     NULL        Y           Y           Y
11          ROWNUMBER11     Y           NULL        Y           Y
12          ROWNUMBER12     Y           Y           NULL        Y
```

The result/output should be

```
ColumnName2
---------------
ROWNUMBER5
ROWNUMBER6
ROWNUMBER7
ROWNUMBER8
ROWNUMBER9
ROWNUMBER10
ROWNUMBER11
ROWNUMBER12
```

The below query will give the expected result. It is not actually a good query and the actual table having 39 rows so the below query won't help. Please help me to get the count based on column in the table.

```
SELECT ColumnName2
FROM TableName
WHERE ColumnName3 = 'Y' AND (ColumnName4 = 'Y' OR ColumnName5 = 'Y' OR  ColumnName6 = 'Y')
OR ColumnName4 = 'Y' AND (ColumnName3 = 'Y' OR ColumnName5 = 'Y' OR  ColumnName6 = 'Y')
OR ColumnName5 = 'Y' AND (ColumnName3 = 'Y' OR ColumnName4 = 'Y' OR  ColumnName6 = 'Y')
OR ColumnName6 = 'Y' AND (ColumnName3 = 'Y' OR ColumnName4 = 'Y' OR  ColumnName5 = 'Y')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to unpivot the columns to rows, then aggregate and filter:

```
select t.columnname2
from tablename t
cross apply (values (columnname3), (columnname4), (columnname5), (columnname6)) as x(columnname)
group by t.columnname2
having sum(case when x.columnname = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) > 1
```

Comment: It helps. One more query will we able to get the count of each column having value 'Y' in single query.